# Getting input field type from lightning:input tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I want to get input field type information in my lightning javascript controller. How is that possible?

For ex:

```
   <lightning:input type="number" value="{!v.value1}"/>
   <lightning:input type="text" value="{!v.value2}"/>
```

Is there any work around or method using which i can get whether the field type is 'text' or 'number' in lightning javascript controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you add an aura:id to your input field, you can access the input element in javaScript Controller:-

```
<lightning:input aura:id="inputCmp" type="number" value="{!v.value1}" />
```

In the controller, you can access the type of the input field as below:-

```
var inputCmp = component.find("inputCmp");
var type = inputCmp.get("v.type");
```